# Accessing Tenant Partnership Information via PowerShell & Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell, charts, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm facing issues with accessing tenant partnership data through PowerShell using Microsoft Graph. I'm particularly focused on using `Get-MgTenantRelationshipDelegatedAdminRelationship` and `Get-MgTenantRelationshipDelegatedAdminCustomer`.
Despite having assigned "DelegatedAdminRelationship.Read.All" and other relevant permissions, I'm not getting the expected outcomes.

Attempted Actions & Expectations:

Action: Authenticated via Connect-MgGraph and executed the mentioned commands.
Permissions: Confirmed my account has "DelegatedAdminRelationship.Read.All".
Expectation: To retrieve detailed data on delegated admin relationships and customers.
Result: Encountered authorization errors or no data returned.
Errors :

> Get-MgTenantRelationshipDelegatedAdminRelationship : You are not
> authorized to access the resource. Status: 401 (Unauthorized)
> ErrorCode: unauthorized Date: 2024-03-01T09:07:43 Headers:
> Transfer-Encoding             : chunked Vary
> : Accept-Encoding Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
> request-id                    : 51583309-64d1-4d66-b506-c128eccb8a61
> client-request-id             : 89376944-beb1-4bee-bda9-f00293cbe93c
> x-ms-ags-diagnostic           : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Central
> US","Slice":"E","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"DS1PEPF000051DF"}}
> Date                          : Fri, 01 Mar 2024 09:07:43 GMT Au
> caractère Ligne:1 : 1
>
> - Get-MgTenantRelationshipDelegatedAdminRelationship
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : ({ Top = , Skip ... , Headers =  }:<>f__AnonymousType6`9)
>   ```
>
> [Get-MgTenantRel...lationship_List], Exception
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : unauthorized,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgTenantRelationshipDelegatedAdminRelationship_List

Questions:

Is there a specific permissions setup or step I'm missing to successfully use these commands?
Are there alternative methods or commands for accessing this information effectively?
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any error details? like error code, error message?

Comment: Maybe some specific role must be assigned to the user. Try to assign Service Support Administrator role to a user.

Comment: I udpdate my poste with the error message

Comment: Could you share the code for authentication? How do you use Connect-MgGraph?

Comment: Connect-MgGraph -Scopes $Scopes
With thoses scopes : @("User.Read.All", "Directory.Read.All", "Application.Read.All", "AuditLog.Read.All", "IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All", "Group.Read.All", "Policy.Read.All", "DelegatedAdminRelationship.Read.All")